# Regserver-like uninstall for non-OLE dll

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way to execute a specific code (or run an external program) before  deleting a dll during uninstall process?

I have a shared dll in my setup and it requires configuration in system registry which should be deleted once the dll is uninstalled - but only when it actually is (i.e. once reference count reaches zero).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can delete those registry settings from code as a post-uninstallation step (`CurUninstallStepChanged` event, `CurUninstallStep == usPostUninstall`) where you check the reference count (we don't know what you use, if it's the `sharedfile` flag or something else) and remove those settings if the count is 0 (or no such counter exists).

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Yes, I use `sharedfile` flag. How can I check the reference count value? Directly reading it from registry or is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: Yes, by [`reading from registry`](http://pastebin.com/drdruksm). There are functions just for incrementing and decrementing the reference count, but not for getting the count at this time.